# How to show that this function is continuous at the point x=0, but not continuous elsewhere with the topological definition?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

for the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (standard topologies) defined by

$f(x)= x$ if $x$ is a rational number
$f(x)= -x$ if $x$ is not rational

Prove that $f$ is continuous at the point $x=0$, but not for any other point.

Comment: Do you know that $f\text{ is continuous}\iff f\text{ is sequentially continuous}?$

Comment: I'm not aware of the definition of sequentially continuous if that's what you're asking

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences) link.

Comment: @Git Gud - This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the topological definition of continuous at a point... i.e. neighborhoods in the domain and codomain

Comment: Hence my question.

Comment: Well, my teacher pointed specifically to the neighborhood definition as the way he wants this solved

Comment: Are you sure it's not $f(x)=0$ for $x$ not rational ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how the problem is written.

Comment: Point 1, what is $\lvert f(x) - f(0)\rvert$? Point 2, if $x_0 \neq 0$, and $\delta > 0$, can you give a lower bound on $$\sup \{ \lvert f(x) - f(x_0)\rvert : \lvert x-x_0\rvert < \delta\}\,?$$

Comment: also not the neighborhoods definition, but I think I figured it out anyways...

Comment: What's your definition of "continuity at a point"?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following proof is correct :

Clearly $f(0)=0$ and for all real $x$, $|f(x)|\leq |x|$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\eta=\epsilon$

Thus $\eta>0$ and then for all real $x$,

$|x|\leq \eta $ implies $|f(x)|\leq |x|<\eta=\epsilon$

Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Now, let $a$ a real number $\neq 0$. We argue in the case where $a$ is irrational (respectively irrational).

Let $\epsilon_0=|a|$; this is a strictly positive real and $\eta >0$.

We choose a irrational (respectively rational ) $x$ such that $a<x<a+\eta$ if $a>0$
and $a-\eta<x<a$ if  $a<0$.

Therefore $|x|>|a|$, so
$$
|f(x)-f(a)|=|0-a|=|a|
$$
(respectively:
$$
|f(x)-f(a)|=|x-0|=|x|>|a|
$$
Thus,
$$
|f(x)-f(a)| \geq\epsilon_0
$$

$f$ is discontinuous at $a$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

The statement appears false.  Consider the open interval $U = (\frac{-1}{4} + \epsilon, \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon)$ for $\epsilon < 1/4$.  The inverse image is $(\mathbb{Q} \cap U) \cup \left( (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}) \cap U \right)$.  The first part of the union includes the rationals in $[0,1/2]$.  The second part contains no irrationals in $[1/4,1/2]$.  This leaves all rationals in $(1/4,1/2]$ without their irrational friends.  Under the usual topology this set of rationals is neither open nor closed. (Its interior is empty, so its not open.  Its closure is the interval $[1/4,1/2]$ so it's not closed (not even close).  Therefore, this set of rationals is neither open nor closed.)  Thus we have found a neighborhood of zero that is not mapped from an open set.  This function is not continuous at zero.  (It isn't continuous anywhere else, for pretty much the same reason.  Continuity isn't preserved when you map a dense subset somewhere else.)

Comment: $f$ is continuous in $0$. All you need is that the preimage of a neighbourhood of $0$ is a neighbourhood of $0$. That is the case here.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  I have explicitly constructed an open set whose preimage is not open.

Comment: For continuity at a point, you don't need that preimages of open sets are open. You only need that preimages of neighbourhoods are neighbourhoods. And since for all $\delta > 0$ we have $f^{-1}((-\delta,\delta)) = (-\delta,\delta)$, that is the case here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: When did all neighborhoods become symmetric?

Comment: Never. But every neighbourhood of $0$ contains a neighbourhood of the form $(-\delta,\delta)$. Indeed, a set is a neighbourhood of $0$ (in the usual topology) if and only if it contains such a symmetric neighbourhood.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  This appears to be moving the goalposts with respect to the argument in your prior comment.  (Aside:  I have inquired with OP about their definition of continuity at a point.)  This definition of continuity at a point seems almost topologically useless.  (So very, very little is metrizable.)

Comment: Sorry, but WHAT? Definition: a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous in $x_0\in X$ if for every neighbourhood $W$ of $f(x_0)$, the preimage $f^{-1}(W)$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$. That is the standard definition. Here we are dealing with $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, and the OP specifically mentioned that the standard topology is used on domain and codomain. In the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, a set $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ if and only if there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subset N$. Pick $x_0=0$, since that is the point where the $f$ here is supposed to be continuous

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Again, you magically make neighborhoods symmetric.  With the standard definition of neighborhood, any open set containing the point of interest, I've constructed a neighborhood with a non-open preimage.  What distinction are you trying to make, since I have exactly produced a counterexample to the definition you have just recited?

Comment: Oh, you use a different definition of neighbourhood. For you a neighbourhood must be open. I use the other standard definition of neighbourhood, $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ if there exists an open $U$ with $x \in U \subset N$. (In my experience the more common definition.) When you require neighbourhoods to be open, the definition of continuity in $x_0$ is "for every neighbourhood $W$ of $f(x_0)$, the preimage $f^{-1}(W)$ **contains** a neighbourhood of $x_0$", not **is** a neighbourhood.

Comment: I hope you have no issue with the fact that if a set $N$ contains an open set $U$ with $0 \in U$, then it contains a set of the form $(-\delta,\delta)$ with $\delta > 0$.

Comment: I do not.  Additionally, I recognize there are neighborhoods of zero that are not symmetric and thus the set of intervals $(-\delta, \delta)$ does not exhaust the set of neighborhoods of zero.

Comment: No, but they form a neighbourhood basis. If every $f^{-1}((-\delta,\delta))$ contains a neighbourhood of $0$, then so does every $f^{-1}(W)$ for an arbitrary neighbourhood $W$ of $0$, since $(-\delta,\delta) \subset W \implies f^{-1}((-\delta,\delta)) \subset f^{-1}(W)$. Therefore it suffices to consider such neighbourhoods of $0$ to determine the continuity of $f$ in $0$.

Comment: Your definition of continuous (with which I agree) does not agree with your usage here.  You have previously written "... the preimage $f^{-1}(W)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$."  You here write that $f^{-1}(W)$ contains a neighborhood of $x_0$.  The former is the definition of continuous.  The latter is not as can be seen by my construction of an open set whose preimage is not open (even though it contains a symmetric open interval about 0).

Comment: Four comments up. I assumed the usual definition of neighbourhood which does **not** require neighbourhoods to be open, until I learned from your comment that you use the one that requires neighbourhoods to be open. With that concept of neighbourhoods, the definition of continuity in a point **cannot sensibly be** that the preimage of a neighbourhood must be a neighbourhood. If you demand neighbourhoods to be open, the definition of continuity in a point is that the preimage of a neighbourhood **contains** a neighbourhood.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Then I believe, having overcome our differences in jargon, we *might* have come to some agreement.  My construction is not a counterexample for this function under the definition of continuity at a point you have suggested.  Since OP has not responded with his definition of continuity at a point, I am unable to reconcile your definition with his.

Comment: Yes, we can certainly agree on that. Absent the OP's definition, Rudin's (RCA, section 1.4), who also defines neighbourhoods as open, might be of interest: "A mapping $f$ of $X$ into $Y$ is said to be _continuous at the point_ $x_0 \in X$ if to every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ there corresponds a neighborhood $W$ of $x_0$ such that $f(W) \subset V$."